# Jquery Find a value in a div, and create meta tag if found

Tags: jquery, metadata

Hey I am looking to do the following,

```
<div class="CesQuerySummary" id="content_0_leftcolumn_0_c_ctl01_ctl00_rs_ctl00_qsm">
  Showing results <b>1</b> - <b>6</b> of <b>6</b>.
</div>
```

In the above mark up find the value of the 3rd  tag which is the total number of search results.

And if found I want to create a meta tag in  section of the page i.e.

```
   //<meta name="WT.oss_r" content="2"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($('.CesQuerySummary b:eq(2)').length !=0 ){

     $('<meta>', {
      name: 'WT.oss_r',
      content: '2'
     }).appendTo('head');

}
```